# Django rest Framework : Behavior of a PrimaryKeyRelatedField with a nested representation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an API built with django rest framework.
Here is the code :

**models.py**

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=13, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    favorite = models.BooleanField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User', related_name="recipes", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Component(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey( Recipe, related_name='components', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.FloatField()
```

**serializers.py**

```
class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    image = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = '__all__'

class ComponentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredient = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Ingredient.objects.all())
    # ingredient = IngredientSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Component
        fields='__all__'

class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    components = ComponentSerializer(many=True)
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = '__all__'
```

With the code in this state, I can create a new component by selecting a existing ingredient, an existing recipe and entering a quantity. However, the serialization of the components is not nested :

```
    {
        "id": 8,
        "quantity": 123.0,
        "ingredient": "3218930313023"
    },
```

When I change the code to `ingredient = IngredientSerializer()` in the ComponentSerializer class, the representation is nested as intended :

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "ingredient": {
        "barcode": "3218930313023",
        "name": "Crêpes L'Authentique",
        "image": "https://static.openfoodfacts.org/images/products/321/893/031/3023/front_fr.16.400.jpg",
    },
    "quantity": 123.0
}
```

But when I try to add a component with an existing recipe and an existing ingredient, I get an Error 400 with the following message :

```
{
    "ingredient": {
        "barcode": [
            "ingredient with this barcode already exists."
        ]
    }
}
```

What would be the best approach to get the same behavior for adding a component as the first code, but with a nested representation, like in the second ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You are using barcode as the primary key which means it must be unique so that's why you got this error.

Comment: But my barcode is unique for each ingredient. Is it possible to implement the fact that if an ingredient with the barcode already exists, it returns it instead of trying to create it ?

Comment: Yes it is, you could just check in the view if it already exist and then return it else continue with the original flow.

Comment: Thank you I will try that !